# Help me rewrite this htaccess rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I rewrite this rule to redirect everything back to the index or server_root?

If there is a request for say, www.site.com/articles/some-article.php, the somearticle.php should be re-routed back to the index page. I also don't want to have the url showing the "index" portion of the URL. site.com/index is where everything should be at.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?dk=$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

OK, I see now what is happening and I think it may help someone to help me better. With my rule, exactly as it is above in my example, I can get the following back into my index.php file with no problems.

```
http://site.com/index/somethin/else/here/test.php
```

Here is what I need:
I need to **remove** the index portion of the url. This url should be rewritten as:
    http://site.com/somethin/else/here/test.php

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite would pass the url to be `www.site.com/index.php?dk=articles/some-article.php`, is that what you are after?

```
RewriteRule ^/articles/(.*)$ index.php?dk=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This should give you `www.site.com/index.php?dk=some-article.php`

```
RewriteRule ^/articles/(.*).php$ index.php?dk=$1 [L,QSA]
```

gives you `www.site.com/index.php?dk=some-article`

Or do you want `www.site.com/?dk=some-article`  ?

Comment: Thanks for responding. What I'm after is to rewrite everything back to the index.php page. So, www.site.com/index.php?dk=some-article.php as well as www.site.com/index.php?dk=something.php&somethingelse=34 should also be rewritten back.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^.*/(.*)$ /?dk=$1 [L,QSA]
```

...if you only want to pass it the file name, or...

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?dk=$1 [L,QSA]
```

...if you want the full path

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, neither of these work and I just don't have enough experience with rewrite to figure out why... Would you know why the full path isn't rewritten?

Comment: All Im getting is page not found.